# function_score scores are rounded

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring

It seems that elasticsearch is rounding scores that comes from function_score.
I have a complex query that use function_score and has_child to sort parent depending on a creation_date date of a child (therefore I can't use sort). The return scores are rounded even in a very simple scenario:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "doc[\"creation_date\"].value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "date": {
      "script": "doc['creation_date'].date"
    },
    "value": {
      "script": "doc['creation_date'].value"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with different script_score :

```
doc["creation_date"].date.getMillis()
```

or (`creation_date_ts` is the same date as a `unixtimestamp`)

```
doc["creation_date_ts"].value
```

or even a literal int:

```
1416398851930
```

But whatever I use I end up with rounded scores.

Here is an example of the results :

```
{
   "_id": "nyrhhh5z",
   "_index": "xxx-1416487038",
   "_score": 1416398900000,
   "_type": "xxx",
   "fields": {
      "date": [
         "2014-11-19T12:07:31.930Z"
      ],
      "value": [
         1416398851930
      ]
   }
}
```

The `_score` should be `1416398851930` (value) be gets rounded to `1416398900000`.
It is a normal behavior, is it documented somewhere (I've searched)? and it there a way to force elasticsearch not to round the scores.

Version of elasticsearch is 1.3.2 (ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Hm. It may be because the value that can be hold as score to be of a type rather limited in precision. 1416398851930 is a really big number. I suggest performing some tests with lower number and I bet that from a number of digits on you will get accurate precision.

Comment: i'll try with the offset from 2010-01-01 for example, thx.

Comment: it works if I use 2013, but not 2010. then it would stop working in a few years. Using 2010 as epoch offset 154098451.93 (yesterday) is rounded to 154098448, I would have thought that's not such a big number.

Comment: rounding is no even consistent 59399774.875 -> 59399776, 59399788.5339999 -> 59399788

Comment: @gwik How is that field mapped? Is it mapped as a `long`?

Comment: @pickypg no date, dateOptionalTime.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm facing a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37799659/2081402) and I'm quite puzzled

Answer (score 1):

The `_score` value is internally hard coded as a float which can only accurately represent integers up to the value 134217728. Therefore, if you want to make use, in the scoring function, of a field stored as a number larger than that, it will overflow the buffer and be truncated. See [this github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17497)