# Custom scoring function in Elasticsearch does not return expected field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I create a custom scoring function for my documents that just returns the value of the field `a` for each document. But for some reason, in the example below, the last digits of the `_score` in the results differ from the last digits of the value of `a` for each document. What is happening here?

```
PUT test/doc/1
{
  "a": 851459198
}

PUT test/doc/2
{
  "a": 984968088
}

GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "doc[\"a\"].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That will return the following:

```
{
  "took": 16,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 984968060,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 984968060,
        "_source": {
          "a": 984968088
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 851459200,
        "_source": {
          "a": 851459198
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why is the `_score` different than the value of the field `a`?

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_score` value is internally hard coded as a float which can only accurately represent integers up to the value 134217728. Therefore, if you want to make use, in the scoring function, of a field stored as a number larger than that, it will overflow the buffer and be truncated. See [this github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17497)